# Trying to deconstruct this Carousel to use on another site

Tags: jquery, carousel

http://www.timewarnercable.com/en/residential-home.html

I really like the way the previous and next images slide into view on this carousel. I have not found anything similar-

Comment: Seems to be a private script... I don't think you can find this legally as jquery plugin.

Comment: From looking at inspector, it appears there are two carousels, one behind and one in front (hero). The two are just timed in such a way that it appears the image is transitioning out. You could start by building off of http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jcarousel.js (http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) using a custom easing script you can grab here: http://easings.net/

I'm pretty certain they're using the "easeInOutCirc" or "easeInOutQuit" formula half way down the page.